# Include siunitx package in subdirectory

Tags: packages, siunitx, folders

I am creating a TeX project that uses the `siunitx` package. I would like to be able to place the `siunitx` package in a subdirectory, to simplify folder structure and to allow me to easily transfer this project to other computers. I know I can [load some packages from subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993965/include-sty-file-from-a-super-subdirectory-of-main-tex-file), but when I try with `siunitx`, I cannot compile my document and get this error:

`! LaTeX Error: File 'siunitx-abbreviations.cfg' not found.`

`siunitx` includes other files, which cannot be reached if the `.sty` file is moved from the root of my project. Is there any way to fix this to allow `siunitx` to find its associated package files?

This is in my TeX document:

```
\usepackage[binary-units=true]{tex_packages/siunitx/siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. Why don't you instal the package (and it's dependencies) using the package manager of your distribution? Seems to bee the safest method. LaTeX needs to find the files, you could add the path so LaTeX can find it, but that is dependent on your distribution (MikTeX, TeX Live, linux packages ...).

Comment: the argument to `\usepackage` should never be a filepath, always a _name_ latex will have warned about the name not matching.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Never trust StackOverflow ;).

Answer (score 23):

The `siunitx.sty` file is a part of package `texlive-science`. Install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-science
```

References: [missing “.sty” package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369268/missing-sty-package).

Comment: <gripe> Is there a 'texlive-get-absolutely-everything-so-i-never-have-to-do-this-again' package? In today's world of 1TB SSD drives standard in cheap laptops, most people can afford to download absolutely everything at once. </gripe>

Comment: Yes, that would be `texlive-full`.

Comment: I just installed texlive-full on a brand new Linux Mint 21 and after testing some tex file, I get:  File `siunitx.sty' not found. -> I wil add it in the local texmf directory :-(

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the `siunitx` package from a subdirectory (strange idea, as mentioned before it's better to install it in your system or local `texmf` directory), you should not only copy the `siunitx.sty` file in the directory but also the files `siunitx-abbreviations.cfg`, `siunitx-binary.cfg` and `siunitx-version-1.cfg` in the same directory, the last one for compatiblity purpose with previous version.